# How resolve dynamic request in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my project existed dynamic requites, some code:

```
var getFrames = require( '../../utils/images' );

module.exports = {
    frameStart: 4, // from 0
    frameStep: 0.033, // seconds
    frameRate: 27.7, // fps
    playRate: 0.1, // percantage
    frameCurrent: 0, // current frame
    frames: getFrames( 'which-ball-lands-first', 52 ),
    width: 320,
    height: 240
},
```

where getFrames function defines like:

```
... 

var getFrames = function( folder, n ) {
  var total = getTotalPower( n );
  var frames = [], i;

  for ( i = 0; i <= n; i++ ) {
    frames.push( require( '../applications/' + folder + '/video/frame-' + getFrameNumber( i, total ) + '.jpg' ) );
  }

  return frames;
};

module.exports = getFrames;
```

But on webpack:build task, for some modules include all jpg images into build.js file, some modules include part of images only... and some modules all images make as assets!

All images are jpg files.
How solve this problem and include all images to build.js?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by webpack [Context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html).

First you have to define a contextual require statement :

```
var req = require.context("../applications/folder/video/", false, /^\.\/.*\.jpg$/);
```

This will include all images in the bundle (I set the second parameter to `false` as your images are directly in this folder).

Then change the `request` by `req` :

```
frames.push(req( '../applications/folder/video/frame-' + getFrameNumber( i, total ) + '.jpg'));
```

I have changed the folder variable to a fixed name for simplicity but you can iterate over several folders if needed.